# ¿Qué error es éste?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, wamp

Instalé **WampServer** y tiene **MySQL** y después **Workbench** pero me aparece un error al querer conectarlo y no sé cuál es ese error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 32: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_Ventas_Clientes1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`Clientes_idCliente' at line 7

Comment: agrega las tablas involucradas así como la consulta SQL que estas ejecutando para poder comprender el error y ayudarte

Comment: El contenido de tu pregunta refiere como si fuera un error de conexión de los componentes de WAMPServer, pero el ERROR que presentas no lo es. Te sugiero modifiques la pregunta para que sea más clara y poder ayudarte!

Comment: Mas que error de instalación se refiere a un error en un query o script que estás intentando ejecutar. Completa tu pregunta si es que se trata de ese caso ;)

Comment: Es un error en un `CREATE TABLE` que usa la palabra clave `VISIBLE` al parecer, la cual [fue añadida en la versión 8 de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-0.html). Trata de actualizar tu motor de base de datos a la versión más reciente y el problema desaparecerá, o bien tendrás que adaptar tus `CREATE TABLE` a la versión que estés usando.