# Al intentar generar script SQL en Workbench, aparece ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy generando el script sql de mi db en Forward Engineer, pero me está saliendo un

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Y no sé por qué exactamente, esto no permite que se me creen todas las tablas que tengo. Me he dado cuenta de que al estar creando llaves foráneas, me empieza a salir este error.

Message Log

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in
> your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
> server version for the right syntax to use near '   CONSTRAINT
> `fk_Usuario_TipoDocumento1`
> FOREIGN KEY (`TipoDocumento_idTipo' at line 19

SQL Code:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `toderos2`.`Usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `toderos2`.`Usuario` (
  `idUsuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Apellido` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Documento` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `FechaNacimiento` DATE NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `EstadoUsuario` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `Direccion` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Barrio` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Ciudad` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Departamento` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `TipoDocumento_idTipoDocumento` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsuario`),
  INDEX `fk_Usuario_TipoDocumento1_idx` (`TipoDocumento_idTipoDocumento` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Usuario_TipoDocumento1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TipoDocumento_idTipoDocumento`)
    REFERENCES `toderos2`.`TipoDocumento` (`idTipoDocumento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch
> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in
> your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
> server version for the right syntax to use near '   CONSTRAINT
> `fk_Usuario_TipoDocumento1`
> FOREIGN KEY (`TipoDocumento_idTipo' at line 19

SQL Code:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `toderos2`.`Usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `toderos2`.`Usuario` (
  `idUsuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Apellido` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Documento` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `FechaNacimiento` DATE NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `EstadoUsuario` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `Direccion` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Barrio` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Ciudad` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Departamento` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `TipoDocumento_idTipoDocumento` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsuario`),
  INDEX `fk_Usuario_TipoDocumento1_idx` (`TipoDocumento_idTipoDocumento` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Usuario_TipoDocumento1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TipoDocumento_idTipoDocumento`)
    REFERENCES `toderos2`.`TipoDocumento` (`idTipoDocumento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch

Comment: El error puede deberse al uso de la palabra `VISIBLE`, que no es admitida en versiones de MySQL anteriores a la `v. 8` ([ver este comentario y el enlace indicado allí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/232197/qué-error-es-éste#comment431340_232197)). Prueba a crear las tablas quitando esa palabra.

Comment: Solucionado, efectivamente era eso, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

El `Error 1064` en este caso es causado por la palabra `VISIBLE` en partes como esta del `CREATE TABLE`:

```
  INDEX `fk_Usuario_TipoDocumento1_idx` 
  (`TipoDocumento_idTipoDocumento` ASC) VISIBLE     
  ...
```

Este error [fue reportado (aunque no reconocido) como un bug en septiembre de 2018](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92269) :

> ... cuando utilizo el asistente de transferencia de esquema de la base
> de datos, siempre obtengo errores porque en la nueva versión de
> Workbench se agregó la palabra clave "VISIBLE". Cómo evitar que esto
> suceda:

El error suele ocurrir cuando se usa el asistente de transferencia de esquema, debido a que las versiones de Workbench superiores a `v. 8` agregan por defecto en el caso de los índices la palabra clave `VISIBLE` y esto debido a que a partir de la versión 8 de MySQL puede haber [índices invisibles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html). Para hacer la diferencia el generador de `CREATE TABLE` añade ahora por tanto la palabra clave `VISIBLE` por defecto.

El problema es que si intentas ejecutar el `CREATE TABLE` así generado en una versión de MySQL inferior a `v. 8` el código terminará en un error de sintaxis, porque la palabra clave `VISIBLE` (tampoco `INVISIBLE`), son reconocidas por dichas versiones.

### Soluciones:

(**a**). Actualizar todo a la versión `8` o superior (recomendado)

O bien:

(**b**). Quitar, donde quiera que aparezca, la palabra clave `VISIBLE` (o `INVISIBLE` si se diera un muy poco probalbe caso), y ejecutar de nuevo la sentencia